# Rounding to the last 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, date

Rounding to the nearest 15 minute interval.
I was wondering if there is a way for me to round up or down to the last  nearest 15 minute interval. i use this function  but beetween H and H=15 minutes, i haven't  no argument.

```
var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear();
var hour = ("0" + now.getUTCHours()).slice(-2);
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var minutes = ("0" + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

var imageUrl = 'image/type'+month+''+day+'.'+hour+''+minutes+'.png',
```

Comment: Took no more than typing “javascript round minutes to 15” into Google to find that, so next time please make a proper research effort before asking.

Answer (score 0):

To round down:

```js
var d = new Date('2001-02-03T04:59:59.999Z'), rounded = new Date( d - d % 9e5 );

console.log( d ); console.log( rounded );        /* 1000 ms * 60 sec * 15 min = 900000 */

console.log( rounded.toJSON().replace(/.*-(..)-(..)T(..):(..).*/, 'image/type$1$2$3$4.png') );
```

---

To round to nearest 15 minutes:

```js
var d = new Date('2001-02-03T04:52:30.000Z'), 
    rounded = new Date( Math.round(d / 9e5) * 9e5 );

console.log( d ); console.log( rounded );
```